# Preposition clarification

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is correct:
"... an officer with the army."
or
"... an officer in the army."

Also, is the general template 'a (official designation) with xyz organization" correct and appropriate in most situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we should use 'in the' when talking about a member of a national armed forces, and 'with the' when talking about being within a specific regiment, battalion, etc.

E.g., 'I am an officer *in* the United States Army, *with* the Army California National Guard.'

This law from New Zealand:

https://legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1990/0028/latest/DLM204978.html

says

an officer is:

> in relation to the Navy, a person who is of or above the rank of
> midshipman or is a chaplain in the Navy; and includes— (i) an officer
> of the Army or the Air Force attached to the Navy or any part of it;
> and (ii) any person duly attached or lent as an officer to or seconded
> for service or appointed for duty as an officer with the Navy:

If we read phrase (ii), then it is referring to a person 'attached or lent as an officer to or seconded for service or appointed for duty as an officer with the Navy'. The first part of this sentence refers to secondment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondment

In the case of secondment, the person is, for example, a member of the Army, but has been seconded to the Navy. It is clearly the case that he is an officer *with* the Navy, because in the formal hierarchy of the Navy he is currently an officer, but that's not his permanent status, he's in fact an officer *in* the Army.

It might be that for example 'a police officer WITH the Knoxville PD' cannot in fact maintain his rank when moving to a different city, so in that sense his rank and service 'with' a specific city cannot be separated from his work there, but that's not important in a linguistic sense, in that Knoxville PD clearly exists as part of a hierarchy of law enforcement, so his police rank can be seen as separate to his specific work for Knoxville.

For positions such as 'company director', we'd use 'of', not 'with' or 'in'. "John is a director of Microsoft", "Fred Jones is the Chairman of IBM."

For other jobs we'd tend to use **at** for our current position. 'I am an engineer at Microsoft' but to talk about the past 'with' might be slightly better 'I was an engineer with Google', but 'with' and 'at' are more-or-less interchangeable in both sentences.

Comment: Compare to “My son is a software engineer **with** Google,” or “My son is a software engineer **at** Google.” Both are fine, and they mean exactly the same thing. For me, an American, unless a position is unique, like “John is **the** CFO **of** Microsoft,” using *of* sounds odd. Perhaps @thelawnet is from NZ, and the usage there differs?

Comment: yes that's true, I should add some more examples.